# twitter bootstrap css clashes while in chrome extensions

Tags: google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, twitter-bootstrap

I am using bootstrap for a chrome extension I am writing. When imported as content script the css seem to clash with alot of the sites I am viewing (even in google search result page).

Wondering if there is anything i can do to scope this to just the dom elements I inject using content script?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

The solution is to use `<style scoped>`.

Essentially it allows you to apply a style to a DOM node and its children, **but not its parent nodes**. There's a nice article on [CSS-Tricks](http://css-tricks.com/saving-the-day-with-scoped-css/) explaining how to use it.

The problem is that it's not very well supported, even in Chrome, so you'll have to use a jQuery polyfill. This is basically a jQuery plugin that simulates the functionality you'd expect from `<style scoped>`.

Here's a working [JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Yqvm7/) doing exactly that using Bootstrap.

Here's an example of how you could implement it in your extension:

**content_script.js**:

```
$.scoped(); // Initialize the plugin
...
bootstrapped = document.createElement("div");
bootstrapped.innerHTML = "<style scoped>";
bootstrapped.innerHTML += "@import url('http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/assets/css/bootstrap.css');";
bootstrapped.innerHTML += "</style>";
document.body.appendChild(bootstrapped);    
...
document.body.appendChild(myDOM); // Will not possess Bootstrap styles
bootstrapped.appendChild(myDOM); // Will possess Bootstrap styles
```

For now, make sure to include jQuery in your page, as well as the Scoped Plugin:

```
"content_scripts": [ {
    "js": [ "jquery.min.js", "jquery.scoped.min.js", "content_script.js" ],
    "matches": [ "http://*" ]
}]
```

Comment: `<style scoped>` specification [here](http://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/the-style-element.html).

The Scoped Plugin is available [here](https://github.com/thingsinjars/jQuery-Scoped-CSS-plugin).

Comment: What if you're not using jQuery? Any way with vanilla JS?